# simple solution for latitude longitude radius

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a scenario in which there are two entities A and B, now both of them has different latitude, longitude and privacy radius, there are three cases.

Case 1: B lies in the radius of A

Case 2: A lies in the radius of B

Case 3: A does not lies in the radius of B

in case 1 and 2 both entities lies in both of the circles
in case 3 both entities lies in the circle of A but A does not lie in the circle of B

Now if there are 100s of posts than does it effect my website performance.

Comment: What are you asking? A question of computation performance?

Answer (score 0):

100s of posts would not affect the webiste performance because:
To distingusih between case1 - 3, you need to calculate only the

1) square of the distance (distSqr) between A and B
and 2) compare distSqr with radB*radB and radA*radA.

These are simple operations.

If you would have some hundred-thousands you will have to think further, e.g using an spatial index.